# Upgrade 14.04 from 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 14.04, system-installation

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I tried to upgrade it to 14.04 by booting from a usb stick. In the menu there were just two options - one was to install 14.04 by erasing 12.04 and another was to install 14.04 by erasing everything. But problem is both of them said that my documents, downloads and musics will be erased totally. Is there a way in which I can upgrade my OS to 14.04 without losing any data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not from a usb stick if I understand correctly. You will have to get online to where you can upgrade directly from the ubuntu servers.

Comment: I am commenting from my PC. So I am online. Now tell me what I have to do?

Comment: Go to a terminal and open update-manager, it will (hopefully) inform you that another LTS version has been released and allow you to upgrade to it.

Comment: It's showing "New Ubuntu release 12.10 is available." not 14.04. :/

Comment: Run the software-properties-gtk program and click the 'updates' tab. Then go down to where it says "Notify me of a new version" and choose 'For long-term support versions', then repeat update-manager.

Comment: Are you sure upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 is supported by Ubuntu? Because I tried it before you told me to do and it wasn't working.

Comment: If it simply doesn't work you could upgrade through all intermediate versions. But did you tell it that you all want it to notify you of new versions on LTS versions?

Comment: Yeah, I did it.

Comment: And it still is notifying you of a non-LTS version? Try  apt-get update  and see if that helps. But if that doesn't work I'll try on a machine that I have that runs 12.04 and see if 14.04 shows up for me.

Comment: After checking at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes I have found that the upgrade you want is not recomended by ubuntu and you will need to first upgrade to 13.10 and then to 14.04. I'm sorry I didn't get this information to you sooner.